# Django does not recognize template_name

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'authentication_system_app',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...,
        'DIRS': ['authentication_system_app/templates/'],
        ...,
    },
]
```

authentication_system_app.urls

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('account/reset-password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='reset_password.html'), name='reset_password'),
```

I don't know why `template_name` is not working on my pet project, but when i watched video tutorial, it worked very well.

I don't know why, can you guys help me. tysm!

GitHub code: [authentication system](https://github.com/truonganhvu205/authentication-system-django)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the template_name, i don't know why it does not work

Comment: It looks like you're conflating `"DIRS": []` and `"APP_DIRS": True`. When you set `APP_DIRS` to `True`, it will check every apps subdirectory with the convention `authentication_system_app/templates/authentication_system_app` for the `template_name` filename. In this case, created `authentication_system_app/templates/authentication_system_app/reset_password.html` and see if it works. It's confusing but fortunately you only have to get it set up once! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong configuration for your templates. See corrections below:

```
 TEMPLATES = [
    {
        •••
        "DIRS": ["templates"], # <—- now all apps and even the base directory will be searched for a folder named "templates".
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        •••
    }
]
```

Comment: By convention [`DjangoTemplates`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates) looks for a *“templates”* subdirectory in each of the `INSTALLED_APPS` so even if you leave `TEMPLATES["DIRS"]` empty, it will still find your templates. Lastly, use *”Template namespacing”* whenever you can.

Answer (score -1):

Create a folder named `templates` in your root directory (same place you have your manage.py file. Afterwards, ensure your `TEMPLATES` list in `settings.py` looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

If you prefer the [method suggested by @FlipperPA in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77843104/django-does-not-recognize-template-name#:%7E:text=It%20looks%20like,FlipperPA), then in your `TEMPLATES` list, use `"DIRS": []` and `"APP_DIRS": True`. This means that you have to create a `templates` folder in your app directory and then create a subfolder with the name of your app in that templates folder and your html file should be in this subfolder. This is quite confusing but basically, in your case, it should look like this: `authentication_system_app/templates/authentication_system_app/reset_password.html`.

Comment: The above method is an *anti-pattern*. Each app and it’s templates should be scoped/isolated. Do not flood the base directory with templates from different apps.

Comment: I presented two methods in my answer right? Did you also look at the second? One can also argue that the second method is quite confusing and repetitive.

Comment: *”…and then create a subfolder with the name of your app in that templates folder and your html file should be in this subfolder”* no you don’t need to create this subfolder unless of course you intend to use template namespace which the OP doesn’t use as seen in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/truonganhvu205/authentication-system-django/tree/main/authentication_system_app/templates)